# Dynamic CSS background image in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I just set up WordPress and tried to install a theme. All is good, but for one simple issue. I know how to make an image dynamic a image in the beginning to set up my index.php, like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="" />
```

but how to make an image dynamic which is called by css

```
.portfolio {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("../img/o-BUSINESS-TECHNOLOGY-facebook.jpg");
}
```

I've tried so  many times but fail. Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: What exactly does "how to dynamic a image" mean?

Comment: did you find the solution? i have done by some way.

Comment: Yes my problem solved. please accept answer from Trix (check the little check mark beside the answer), as this is right solution to this problem, for any further reference. That would be useful for others

Answer (score 5):

You should note that Wordpress has an standard way to add `<script>`s and `<style>`s to the `<head>` section of your web document, which is using `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, but regarding your question, I will try to provide the desired way:

You may put that particular CSS in `<style>` tags in your documents `<head>` section and use:

```
.portfolio {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/o-BUSINESS-TECHNOLOGY-facebook.jpg");
}
```

### UPDATE

Although, this seems to work and let you have the desired output, I strongly recommend you do not use it, because you may use:

```
.portfolio {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("img/o-BUSINESS-TECHNOLOGY-facebook.jpg");
}
```

in your `style.css` file and still get the same result.

I really do not know what kind of **dynamic** CSS, are you after, but If you really want it to be dynamic and you are sure about what you are doing, you have two methods:

1. The above method (adding styles to `<style>` tag in `<head>` section of document)
2. making your stylesheet file dynamic, using PHP (which you may get a tutorial on [this](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) link, or google for **dynamic stylesheet php**)

Comment: thanks trix it works .if i have 10 to more css images is that all time use the same code.or have any other way.and what can i do with my old stylsheet code deleted or remain the old code

Comment: the update looks wrong, the img folder is pretty much never in the document root.

Comment: @tacone relative paths in `style.css` regard current theme's root, not the document's root.

Comment: @trix `background-image: url("/img/o-BUSINESS-TECHNOLOGY-facebook.jpg");` is not a relative path.

Comment: is that method is not correct? what method you both use @trix and @ tacno .your first code is look likes ok but which issue is happened if i use the code.

Comment: This **is not the WordPress way.** You would not want to write *anything* inside the `<head>` tags directly in the template.  You do these things via actions and filters, and functions (typically in your theme's `functions.php` file).

Comment: @cale_b that is exactly true, but regarding the scope of the question asked, I tried to provide a way the user is after.

Comment: Fair enough.  At least *comment in your question* that this isn't the WordPress way, and show an example of what it would look like.  We're trying to build an *authoritative site* of questions and answers, and this is only half the answer.